# How to continue a conversation from the comments if we go off-topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, comments

I answered a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/when-should-i-use-is-and-when-does/5345?noredirect=1#comment7906_5345) recently and it was marked the best answer. Later I made a comment, which provoked a reaction from one of the people who had also answered. This led to a dialogue between us, which is, in my opinion, off-topic for most of its part.

- I would like to make my point clear to this person and understand their point, but not as comments to that particular question, as it is off-topic.
- This person is not in the chat.
- Nobody else seems to be interested in the conversation and they would probably appreciate if they were not reminded of it every time one of us made yet another comment.

What can I do since there is no possibility to send private messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the exchange of comments is just between two users, a message suggesting to continue in chat would appear, at some point; if you click on the link shown in that message, a chat room is created, and the comments copied there. At that point, the other user would see a message ("Let's continue on chat") containing a link to the chat room.
As far as I know, that doesn't happen when at least one of the users doesn't have the privilege of chatting.

If that doesn't happen, you could write a comment inviting the other user in chat.
I would go in chat, write the link to the answer in a post, write a comment for that answer inviting the user to chat, giving a link to that chat post you created. In that way, the other user can reply to your chat post, and make you know there is a reply for you.

Notice that the reputation required to talk in a chat room is 20 (the same reputation that will be required when the site graduates), and the reputation required to create chat room is 100. You can create a new chat room with the purpose of chatting about that topic. If you want, you can also copy the comments as first posts in that chat room; then, you can give the room link in a comment for the other user.

Comment: No message has appeared so far. Let's say I want to go to an existing room in the chat. There is no "invite users to chat" button. Do you suggest that I write one final comment, giving a link to the chat?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest so. See what I added in my answer.

Comment: @fluffy Note that, if the comments are off-topic, you should then flag for moderator attention so we can delete the comments. We will leave the link to the chat room, of course, so you can continue your discussion. (This is actually what moderators do when we decide your discussion is a better fit for chat, and manually create the chat room ourselves.).  Great answer kiamlaluno, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will know next time something like this happens